# how can I check for bounties from a saved position to the current position of the player

Tags: scala, function, delegates, 2d

```
/**
  * Updates saveX and saveY to the current player position.
  */
  def save(): Unit = {
  saveX = playerX
  saveY = playerY
  }

 /**
 * Returns the current save position as a tuple, in (x,y) order.
 */
def getSavePos(): (Int, Int) =  {
return (saveX, saveY);
}

def checkBounty() {
if(bounties (playerX)(playerY) != null){
  var bounty: Int => Int = bounties(playerX)(playerY)
  score = bounty(score)
  bounties(playerX)(playerY) == null
  }
}
```

The checkBounty() function checks for bounties in the current position of the player which is (playerX, playerY) if there is a bounty it is collected and the bounty is then removed hence bounties(playerX)(playerY) == null

```
/**
  * Checks if the rectangle defined by the current position and saved position 
  * covers nine or more positions. If yes, it collects bounties in it, increases the 
  * score, and erases the bounties.
  */
  def checkBounties() {
  if(((playerX - saveX)+1).abs * ((playerY - saveY) + 1).abs >= 9){

  for(x <-  saveX to playerX; y <- saveY to playerY){

    checkBounty(); 
  }
  saveX = -1
  saveY = -1
  }
}
```

the checkBounties() function does what it says in the comment and also if 9 or more positions are covered sets the save position back to (-1,-1).
I tried the for loop to check for any bounties that are within the saved position and current position after it moves from the saved position, I then delegated the checkBounty() function so it does that for each cell moved between the saved and current position. 
But this code doesnt exactly work as I expected it to the saveX and saveY in the for loop isnt representing the saved X and Y positions and instead its saveX is -1 and saveY is -1, so it is checking for bounties from -1 to playerX but I need it to check form the last saved position to playerX

Comment: not entirely sure I understand all this, but offhand, it looks to me like your `checkBounty` method ought to take `x` and `y` parameters and use those, instead of always using `playerX` and `playerY`. otherwise the `for `loop in `checkBounties` doesn't make sense.

Comment: i tried that but still doesnt work

Comment: Okay, but then we'll need to see your attempt, and your explanation of what happened (not just "it didn't work"). Hopefully Boris's answer will help.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem that you are don't use `x` and `y` from for loop in `checkBounty()`. Maybe passing them as arguments will solve your issue:

```
def checkBounty(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
  if(bounties (x)(y) != null){
    val bounty: Int => Int = bounties(x)(y)
    score += bounty(score)
    bounties(x)(y) == null
  }
  score
}

def checkBounties() {
  if (((playerX - saveX) + 1).abs * ((playerY - saveY) + 1).abs >= 9) {

    for (x <- saveX to playerX; y <- saveY to playerY) {

      checkBounty(x, y);
    }
    saveX = -1
    saveY = -1
  }

}
```

Also, using mutable statements is bad practise in scala. If you want to use mutable variables I would advise you using `Ref` or you can rewrite you code using immutable structures.

Comment: I wrote the exact code as yours change the players to x and playerY to y the test for this function still fails. The test fails because the checkBounty() is not being implemented. Its supposed to return a score of 2 but instead returns 0. which means it is not checking for bounties in x and y values

Comment: @SurajOdedra Maybe `checkBounty ` should return `score`. Updated answer

Comment: still the same and when I keep score in checkBounty it gives me this warning
◾a pure expression does nothing in statement position
◾multiline expressions might require enclosing parentheses; a value can be silently discarded when Unit is expected

Comment: @SurajOdedra Are your `bounties` is correct? What does it store?

Comment: private var bounties: Array[Array[Int=>Int]] = Array.ofDim[Int=>Int](10, 10)
  bounty.foreach(w => bounties(w._1)(w._2)=w._3)

Comment: @SurajOdedra My bad, error was in line `score = bounty(score)`, assume it should be `score += bounty(score)`